# Locus of a certain point such that $|z-a||z-b|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

What is the locus of a point moving in such a way that the product of its distance from two fixed points is equal to $1$? In terms of complex numbers, let $a$, $b$ be two fixed points in the plane and $z$ be a variable complex number, then the locus we are seeking is:
$$|z-a||z-b|=1$$

I tried to plot for $a=1$, $b=2$ and I am getting something like an ellipse but as I replace $1$ by some larger number  I am get something like a circle.

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

Comment: I’ve edited “…that the product of its distance…”

Answer (score 4):

The locus of points $P$ such that the product of distances $PP_1$ and $PP_2$ from two fixed points $P_1$ and $P_2$ is constant is known as [Cassini oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval)

[image]
([credits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_oval#/media/File:Cassini-k-def0.svg))

---

Take a look here for a nice [interactive demonstration](https://www.geogebra.org/m/NJ6ckHQ3) by Steve Phelps.

Comment: "The locus where the... " $\to$ "The locus *of points P such that* the product PA.PB is constant

Comment: Thanks! I fix that